# Возможно ли вставить значение переменной как значение ключа?

Tags: javascript

у меня есть переменная и я хочу сделать так, чтобы у ключа было значение переменной. но постоянно проверять значение и по результату вставлять мне кажется плохим вариантом. возможно ли сделать так, чтобы значение ключа имело значение этой переменной?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, обращайтесь через квадратные скобки.

```js
const user =
{
  name: "Tupac",
  age: 50
};

const var1 = 'name';
const var2 = 'age';

console.log(user[var1]);
console.log(user[var2]);
```